# Can I play audio file using videojs library?

Tags: video.js

I am using videojs : http://videojs.com/

Can you guys please help me if I can play audio files using videojs library.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
<audio id="audio_example" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" 
  width="600" height="600" poster="/img/awesome-album-art.png" data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="/audio/awesome-music.mp3" type='audio/mp3'/>
</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you please provide detail if you have this using data-setup in javascript, how can we achive this I have gone through many posts and it seems there are issues with only audio player.